# What is this round part with Technic holes in the middle?

Tags: part-identification

Can someone please tell me what this part is called? I'm looking for what kinds of sets it may have been used in.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is [Wheel Hard Plastic with Small Cleats and Flanges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64712#T=P) (64712). This element in Olive Green color was part of a [single set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=64712&colorID=155&in=A). While Black colored one was included in [18 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=64712&colorID=11&in=A).

Comment: Ah dang, beat me to it by the span of a bathroom break :) Take my upvote, sir.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Buying bulk Lego without instructions booklets  has has been equal parts joyful and woeful as I try and help my son create and make different things. Thanks so much for all the help!